# workout program for weight increase

Tags: programs

I created my self a program, I just wanted to be sure if this is realistic and achivable. starting point what I can do right now.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12CtPBiob9z2ldYrgoGgDEFp09liBYNQXuDdfJZvGpMQ/edit?usp=sharing

173cm 68kg 30yo

Comment: You're asking for an opinion based on the very little (if at all) that we know of you.

Comment: I did add some info, anything else please feel free to ask.

Comment: Why not just start out with an already established beginner's program? You'll get a very good foundation, and you'll learn a little about how decent programs are organised.

Comment: they dont have anything about how much weight I should use and how frequently I should increase. or do they?

Comment: They don't give explicit numbers to start at (aside from StrongLifts which advocates some start with the 45 lb bar), but they all tell you how to find the weights to use in the beginning and then how to progress from there.

Answer (score 2):

Your results will depend on the calorie surplus. A large surplus will lead to increases in large increases in both muscle and fat, it will also lead to large strength increases.

Most of the progressions look realistic to me if you have little experience of strength training. Deltoid raises and seated cable rows look a bit optimistic. Is there a particular reasons why you expect certain lifts to increase more than others?

Other than that, I'd give two advice:

1. Do legs and hip as well, if your aim is to increase mass you shouldn't ignore half of your body, and even if you only care about aestetics, thin legs look ridiculous on a developed upper body.
2. Find a more difficult ab exercise, there are many ways to workout your abs that won't require you to do 50 reps (which won't result in any hypertrophy)

edit: I just noticed your dates. Are you intending to workout once per week only? Then you can not expect such strength increases.

Comment: once every muscle group,Its like every week one chest day,one shoulder day,one back day ect.. should I do twice in a week?

Comment: When you do splits and have chest days and such, the volume is typically much higher, doing about 9 sets for every muscle group involved, and I don't think doing chest day, back day and leg day on the same day would work, that would probably be too much to recover from.